# How to set indicatorType in KingFisher v5.0.0 from inside an extension on UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

I was able to to do something like this (using version `4.10.1`):

```
extension UIImageView {
    func test() {
        self.kf.indicatorType = .activity
    }
}
```

now with version 5.0.0 this is no longer possible with the following error:

> Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable

I still can set it normally from outside the extension. Is there a way to set the indictorType from inside the `UIImageView` extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in this issue on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/issues/1064) of the library, it turns out that `kf` variable now refers to a struct for performance considerations in `Kingfisher`, so to handle it we need to a create a copy for it like the following:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func test() {
        var kf = self.kf
        kf.indicatorType = .activity
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. There is also an issue for it: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/issues/1064

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UIImageView {
 func setImages(url:String){
    let activityInd = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    activityInd.center = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width  / 2,
                                 y: self.frame.size.height / 2)
    activityInd.color = UIColor.red
    self.addSubview(activityInd)
    activityInd.startAnimating()
    self.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: url), placeholder: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user-icn"), options: nil, progressBlock: nil) { (img, err, cache, url) in
        activityInd.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

}